# Samsung Gear VR - create Menus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, menu, oculus, gear-vr

how can I create Menu in my application , I use canvas , but Gear VR  Camera dosent see it .

is there way , to use button in gear application

3d text appear but not canvas text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use screen space ui with VR, switch to [world space](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html) and either place it somewhere in the scene (as a "real" object) or parent it to the camera so it is always in the center of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

ChanibaL is right, canvas can not be used in screen space.

Last time, when I design a menu in vr. I add sphere out of the camera, with a full black color. And put the ui buttons inner the sphere as a menu.

I think this may help for you.

More about UI design in vr, I advice to read this post [UI for VR](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/user-interfaces-vr?playlist=22946)